# yaml-cpp link error on MacOS and gcc-4.8

Tags: c++, homebrew, yaml-cpp

I have issues linking yaml-cpp code. The weird thing is that it is compiler dependent. I am using homebrew to get yaml-cpp and gcc-4.8 . I have a simple program

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main(){
  YAML::Node yparams_;
  yparams = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");

  printf("all good\n");
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine, if I use the 'g++' provided with mac

```
g++ test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs yaml-cpp) -o test
```

However, exchanging 'g++' to the homebrewed 'g++-4.8' gives me a long list of linker errors (attached below). If I run 'brew doctor' I do not get any warning. 'brew info yaml-cpp' returns with:

```
yaml-cpp: stable 0.5.1
http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/
/usr/local/Cellar/yaml-cpp/0.5.1 (40 files, 1.0M) *
  Built from source with: --c++11
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/yaml-cpp.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔
Required: boost ✔
```

The output of 'brew info gcc' is

```
gcc: stable 4.8.3 (bottled), HEAD
http://gcc.gnu.org
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1 (1046 files, 184M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gcc.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gmp ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔, cloog ✔, isl ✔
```

I appreciate any hint on how to fix this issue. Thanks!

```
  "YAML::LoadFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccG1oCNG.o
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<YAML::detail::node*, std::__1::allocator<YAML::detail::node*> >::__push_back_slow_path<YAML::detail::node*>(YAML::detail::node*&&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_ in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      YAML::Exception::Exception(YAML::Mark const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      YAML::BadSubscript::BadSubscript() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::BadPushback::BadPushback() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      YAML::Exception::Exception(YAML::Mark const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<YAML::detail::node_data>(YAML::detail::node_data*) in libyaml-cpp.a(memory.cpp.o)
      boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<YAML::detail::node_data>::dispose()     in libyaml-cpp.a(memory.cpp.o)
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::BadPushback::~BadPushback() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::BadSubscript::~BadSubscript() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::set_tag(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::detail::node_data::set_scalar(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::detail::node_ref::set_scalar(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      YAML::Exception::build_what(YAML::Mark const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sync()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::uflow()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::Exception::build_what(YAML::Mark const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::init(void*)", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      YAML::Exception::build_what(YAML::Mark const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios()", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node_data::convert_sequence_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      ...
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libyaml-cpp.a(node_data.cpp.o)
```

Comment: You generally cannot link together things built with different C++ compilers, or different versions of the same compiler. You will get linker errors at best, mysterious crashes at run time or incorrect results at worst.

Comment: More precisely, it looks like your preinstalled gcc uses libc++, and is therefore probably a clang++ in disguise, while your brewed g++ is a bona fide g++ using libstdc++. Check it witg g++ -v or whatever. If this is the case, you cannot use the two compilers together to compile interdependent pieces of C++ code in the same prigram.

Comment: You are right, the preinstalled gcc is a clang compiler. I guess homebrew uses the preinstalled compiler to install yaml-cpp. This is probably the reason, why I cannot link against it, when I use the custom gcc-4.8 to build my test program ...